# How to add data into a new line of a txt file

Tags: c, file, insert

**So, if I have something like this on a txt file:**

> file.txt;5;12:40
>
> file2.txt;6;13:40

**I want in the program to add another line such as**

***"file3.txt;7;12:40"***

**To be like:**

> file.txt;5;12:40
>
> file2.txt;6;13:40
>
> file3.txt;7;12:40

**Yet when I do it with my code, it stays like:**

> file.txt;5;12:40
>
> file2.txt;6;13:40file3.txt;7;12:40

**My code** *(I took the if's about if the file exists or not to be more simple to see the real code):*

```
printf("Insert the name of the file\n");
printf("[Name] ");
getchar();
scanf("%[^\n]s",&orderNameFile);
printf("\n");
                
orderFile = fopen("order.txt","a");
contentFile = fopen(orderNameFile,"r");

// This is supposed to be into an if
printf("Insert the seconds for presentation\n");
printf("[Time in seconds] ");
scanf("%d",&orderSecondsFile);

printf("Insert the time\n");
printf("[Time HH:MM (Hour:Minutes)] ");
getchar();
scanf("%[^\n]s",&orderTimeFile);
printf("\n");

fprintf(orderFile,"%s;%d;%s\n", orderNameFile, orderSecondsFile, orderTimeFile);
opOrder = 1;

fclose(contentFile);
```

I've tried to take the \n out of the fprintf and make another, put it on the beginning, on the ending, but it won't make an enter into a txt file.

Any idea of how to do it?

**Output:**

> file.txt;5;12:40
>
> file2.txt;6;13:40file3.txt;7;12:40

**What I want:**

> file.txt;5;12:40
>
> file2.txt;6;13:40
>
> file3.txt;7;12:40

Comment: It seems that the '\n' is missing at the end of file. The easiest solution would be printing "\n%s;%d;%s\n" to the orderFile. More general solution would be to look at the last character of orderFile and check whether it is '\n' or not and print it only if not. Otherwise you could just print "\n%s;%d;%s" in order to respect the previous format not ending with '\n' so you don't end up with double EoLs next time you append again.

Comment: "wb" will recreate the content that there exists, so it's a no solution. Also did the attempt of "\n%s;%d;%s\n" but it's the same thing as not having any, no enters will be given.

Comment: Looks like you have answered the question Alegnem.  +1 :-) I think this should of be an answer for Ran.

Comment: have you examined the order.txt file to assure it already contains a trailing '\n' (typically 0x0a 0x0d)

Comment: Used gopi way and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: the scanf() should not have a preceeding call to getchar() to try and consume white space.  Instead, removed the call to getline() and insert a leading ' ' (space) in the scanf format string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
orderFile = fopen("order.txt","wt");
```

or

```
fprintf(orderFile,"\r\n");
```

Comment: Thank you, the \r\n worked perfectly. May you explain me what does the \r means?

Comment: @Ran Are you on windows?

Comment: Yes I am. Why do you ask? (Sorry was creating code for the rest of the software)

Comment: @Ran On unix systems this is not required AFAIK but to have backward compatibilty with DOS on windows there is \r\n so that \r will  makes sure you get \n. Check the link http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n